# способ добавить cleanup-code в легаси код

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Есть условная легаси функция (2к строк) с кучей точек завершения.

```
long foo(...)
{
    if (statement1)
        return -1;

    if (statement2)
        return -2;

    for (...)
    {
        if(...)
            return -3;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

Функция модифируется и возникает необходимость перед каждым return вызвать определенный cleanup код, обернуть этот код в локальный объект, который бы автоматически разрушался при завершении функции не получается.
Вариант обернуть тело функции в try-catch наверное не подходит т.к. функция частично перебрасывает исключения наверх, частично обрабатывает своими силами и наверняка будет некий сайд-эффект от такого способа.

Есть ли способы сделать это без дописывания cleanup-code к каждому return?

дело под виндой, vs2015

P.S. пока придумалось вместо каждого return  вызывать лямбду/функцию, которая будет вызывать cleanup-code и делать return

Comment: И почему же обернуть ресурсы в RAII не получается? Тогда уже разбивать всю функцию нормально, а не делать костыли.

Comment: Сказали А, говорите Б - что за такой хитрый код, который обернуть в объект не получается, а в лямбду - запросто...?

Comment: Си маньяки обычно используют goto : `retvalue = ... ; goto CleanUp ; ... CleanUp : ... return retvalue ;` Попробуйте, если в вашей в религии так можно.

Comment: Приводите конкретный пример. А то непонятно, отчего это вдруг "*обернуть этот код в локальный объект, который бы автоматически разрушался при завершении функции не получается*"

Comment: я затупил, забыл что можно функции с параметрами можно обернуть в RAII)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен [scope guard](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WjTrfoiB0MQ).

Работает это примерно так:

```cpp
FILE *f = std::fopen(...);
if (!f) throw ...;
FINALLY( std::fclose(f); )
// Тут используется `f`.
```

Здесь `FINALLY` - это макрос, тот самый scope guard.

Код внутри scope guard вызывается не сразу, а после выхода из области видимости (у вас - после выхода из функции).

Реализацию scope guard можно нагуглить, а можно написать свою (это несложно).

Я обычно использую вот такой вариант:

```
namespace Macro
{
    template <typename T> class FinallyObject
    {
        T func;

      public:
        FinallyObject(T &&func) : func(std::move(func)) {}
        FinallyObject(const FinallyObject &) = delete;
        FinallyObject &operator=(const FinallyObject &) = delete;
        ~FinallyObject()
        {
            func();
        }
    };
}

#define FINALLY_impl_cat(a, b) FINALLY_impl_cat_(a, b)
#define FINALLY_impl_cat_(a, b) a##b

#define FINALLY(...) \
    ::Macro::FinallyObject FINALLY_impl_cat(_finally_object_,__LINE__) \
    ([&]{ __VA_ARGS__ });

// Как обычный FINALLY, но выполняется только при выбросе исключения.    
#define FINALLY_ON_THROW(...) \
    ::Macro::FinallyObject FINALLY_impl_cat(_finally_object_,__LINE__) \
    ([&, _finally_exc_depth_ = ::std::uncaught_exceptions()] \
    { if (::std::uncaught_exceptions() != _finally_exc_depth_) {__VA_ARGS__} });

// Наоборот, выполняется если вызов деструктора произошел из-за нормального
// выхода из scope, а не из-за исключения.
#define FINALLY_ON_SUCCESS(...) \
    ::Macro::FinallyObject FINALLY_impl_cat(_finally_object_,__LINE__) \
    ([&, _finally_exc_depth_ = ::std::uncaught_exceptions()] \
    { if (::std::uncaught_exceptions() == _finally_exc_depth_) {__VA_ARGS__} });
```

---

Вот переделанная версия, которая работает без С++17.

**Предупреждение:** В этом варианте мы вынуждены использовать `std::uncaught_exception` вместо `std::uncaught_exceptions`, поэтому в некоторых редких случаях обнаружение исключений (макросы `FINALLY_ON_THROW` и `FINALLY_ON_SUCCESS`) будут работать некорректно.

Например, если они используются внутри деструктора (в том числе в любой вызванной им функции), и этот деструктор был вызван из-за исключения, то макросы `FINALLY_ON_THROW` и `FINALLY_ON_SUCCESS` будут учитывать это исключение (первый вызовет свой код, а второй - нет). Это - неправильное поведение, так как учитываться должны только *новые* исключения (выброшенные *после* прохода выполнения через макрос).

```cpp
namespace Macro
{
    template <typename T> class FinallyObject
    {
        T func;

      public:
        FinallyObject(T &&func) : func(std::move(func)) {}
        FinallyObject(FinallyObject &&) = default;
        FinallyObject &operator=(const FinallyObject &) = delete;
        ~FinallyObject()
        {
            func();
        }
    };

    template <typename T>
    FinallyObject<T> MakeFinallyObject(T &&func)
    {
        return {std::move(func)};
    }
}

#define FINALLY_impl_cat(a, b) FINALLY_impl_cat_(a, b)
#define FINALLY_impl_cat_(a, b) a##b

#define FINALLY(...) \
    auto FINALLY_impl_cat(_finally_object_,__LINE__) = ::Macro::MakeFinallyObject([&]{ __VA_ARGS__ });

// Как обычный FINALLY, но выполняется только при выбросе исключения.
#define FINALLY_ON_THROW(...) \
    FINALLY( if (::std::uncaught_exception()) {__VA_ARGS__} )

// Наоборот, выполняется если вызов деструктора произошел из-за нормального
// выхода из scope, а не из-за исключения.
#define FINALLY_ON_SUCCESS(...) \
    FINALLY( if (!::std::uncaught_exception()) {__VA_ARGS__} )
```